# Submit form containing inputs and a table

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a form containing a grid in Dotnet core 6.
This works only if input name="Materials[' + counter + '].Amount" is in order,
0,1,2,3,4, etc.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="grid2" style="width:100%;display:hidden;border-color:#1274AC;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="width:100%;">
        <th style="width:auto;border-radius:5px;padding-left:12px">Item Number</th>
        <th style="width:auto;border-radius:5px;padding-left:12px">Description</th>
        <th style="width:auto;border-radius:5px;padding-left:12px">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.POMaterials[0].Amount)</th>
        <th style="width:auto;border-radius:5px;padding-left:12px">Unit Cost</th>
        @*<th style="width:25%;border-radius:5px;padding-left:12px">Total</th>*@
        <th colspan="2" style="width:auto;border-radius:5px;padding-left:12px">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
<div style="margin-top:5px;"></div>
<button onclick="addRow()" id="bt" title="Add Another Record" type="button" class="btn btn-sm" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-plus"></span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm" type="reset" title="Clear All Fields" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;">
    <span class="k-icon"><img src="~/Images/eraser.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;" /></span>
</button>
<button id="calc" onClick="findTotal()" title="Calculate Total" type="button" class="btn btn-sm" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-plus-circle"></span>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    function addRow() {
        var table = document.getElementById("grid2");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        //var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="POMaterials[' + counter + '].ItemNumber" name="POMaterials[' + counter + '].ItemNumber" style="width:auto;border-radius:5px;" required/>';//Materials[' + counter + '].ItemDescription
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="POMaterials[' + counter + '].Description" name="POMaterials[' + counter + '].Description" style="border-radius:5px;width:auto;" required/>';
        cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="POMaterials[' + counter + '].Amount" name="POMaterials[' + counter + '].Amount" class="andi" style="border-radius:5px;width:auto;" required/>'; //Materials[' + counter + '].Amount
        cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="POMaterials[' + counter + '].UnitCost" name="POMaterials[' + counter + '].UnitCost" class="andi" style="border-radius:5px;width:auto;" required/>';
        //cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="Total[' + counter + ']" name="Total[' + counter + ']" class="kita" style="border-radius:5px;width:auto;" required/>';
        cell5.innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="clearrow" onClick="removeCurrentRow()" class="btn btn-sm" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px lightgray;" title="Remove Entry"><span class="k-icon k-i-minus" ></span></button>';
        counter++;
    }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function removeCurrentRow() {
        var index, table = document.getElementById('grid2');
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            table.rows[i].cells[4].onclick = function () {
                index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
                table.deleteRow(index);
                counter--;
                console.log(index);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

If I were to remove a row from the bottom then it works, but if I were to remove a row from any other row than it breaks the counter flow, and data does not pass to the controller.

Is there a way to implement that no matter which row to remove it loads the page and reorders the rest of the inputs with javaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below JavaScript code to reorder the rows:

```
function removeCurrentRow() {
    var index, table = document.getElementById('grid2');
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].cells[4].onclick = function () {
            index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
            table.deleteRow(index);
            counter--;
            reorderRows(); // Reorder after removing a row
        }
    }
}

function reorderRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById('grid2');
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].ItemNumber';
        row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].ItemNumber';

        row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].Description';
        row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].Description';

        row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].Amount';
        row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].Amount';

        row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].UnitCost';
        row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id = 'POMaterials[' + (i-1) + '].UnitCost';
    }
}
```

or by using

```
function removeCurrentRow() {
    $('#grid2 tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        
        // Reset counter and reindex input names
        counter--;
        reindexRows();
    });
}

function reindexRows() {
    $('#grid2 tbody tr').each(function(rowIndex) {
        $(this).find('input').each(function(inputIndex) {
            var newInputName;
            switch (inputIndex) {
                case 0:
                    newInputName = 'POMaterials[' + rowIndex + '].ItemNumber';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    newInputName = 'POMaterials[' + rowIndex + '].Description';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    newInputName = 'POMaterials[' + rowIndex + '].Amount';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    newInputName = 'POMaterials[' + rowIndex + '].UnitCost';
                    break;
            }
            $(this).attr('name', newInputName);
        });
    });
}
```